# Can't set Access-Control-Allow-Origin request header

Tags: ajax, xmlhttprequest

I making an AJAX request to the [food2fork](http://food2fork.com/about/api) api and can't get by the **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present** error. I've tried setting the header in `beforeSend` and setting `crossDomain: true` but it didn't work.

This is my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      dataType: 'json',
      url: url,
      crossDomain: true, 
      beforeSend: function(xhr) {
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      },
      success: function(data){
          console.log('in ajax json call');
          console.log(data);
          $('#info').html(JSON.stringify(data));
      }
    });
```

I tried setting the request header server side in node express.js with:

```
router.get('/test', cors(), function(req,res)
{
  res.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); //set header here
  res.render('exampleSearch', {title: 'FM | Test'});
});
```

[Cors](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) is an npm package that sets cross-reference permissions but didn't help me solve the problem.

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: That's a _response_ header.  What happens when you send it in the response?

Comment: @SLaks I'm not sure what happens when I send it in the response, I'm a begginer at server-side coding :) My guess it just assigns the parameter which doesn't do anything.

I removed it and the same error occurs, can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side request doesn't work in this case. I had to do the request server side:

```
router.post('/test', function(req,res){

var callback = function(response){
 var str = '';

 //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
   str += chunk;
 });

 //the whole response has been recieved
 response.on('end', function () {
   var recipes = JSON.parse(str);
   //do something with recipes
 });
}

var options = {
 host: "food2fork.com",
 path: "/api/search?key=[myKey]&q=" + ingredients
};

http.request(options,callback).end();

});
```

Used code from [nodejitsu.com](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request)